# Working in the dark on an OLE application

Tags: object, ms-access, vba, typelib

I am working in the dark. There is an application installed on my PC by the corporate fathers that allows programmatic access to a library of reports. I can't get anyone to tell me the application's properties or methods (apart from a couple methods found in some scripts....)

I'm using Access VBA to get to the application, and it does load it up (it shows a GUI when the CreateObject() statement is executed.)

How can I get it to list its properties and methods once I invoke it? You can see my effort, but it fails saying "Object doesn't support this property or method" when it executes the "for each" statement.

```
Sub StartDataNav()
  Set oleDataNav = CreateObject("DataNavigator.Application")
  Dim p As Object
  For Each p In oleDataNav.Properties

  Next p

End Sub
```

If need be, I can change to C#.net, but I'm not as experienced invoking what I assume is a non-managed application....

Comment: I decided that the object must be registered, so I fired up Visual Studio and created a C#.net console app, then set a reference to the DataNavigator object. Intellisense now reveals the methods, though it shows no properties at all (which probably explains the problem with the "for each" statement above.) I've been muddling through so far, though all the parameters of all the methods are objects with no information other than their name. I'm getting error codes back and can't interpret them. Sux....

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TlbInf32.dll (TLI) to inspect the public members of the target application. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985086.aspx seems to be a good start.

Or just inspect TLI itself using the object browser (after referencing it in the VBE).

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint on your line

```
Dim p As Object
```

and open the locals window (View --> Locals).

This will let you see all the properties of your object by expanding the oleDataNav object in the locals window.